# SQL to get unique count based on other column values

Tags: sql

How to get count of ID's having status other then cancelled. If StatusType = Cancelled then that ID not be considered in the count in MemSQL.

Expected:
count =2

10004 = Available and Not started

10006 = Not started

```
ID      StatusType
10001   NULL
10001   Available
10001   Not Started
10001   Cancelled
10002   Cancelled
10002   Not Started
10003   Available
10003   NULL
10003   Cancelled
10004   Available
10004   Not Started
10005   Cancelled
10006   Not Started
```

Comment: I've removed most of the tags here, as they didn't appear relevant or conflicted. Please tag correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two steps. First do a GROUP BY with HAVING to find ID's without Cancelled. Then count these ID's.

```
select count(*)
from (
    select ID
    from tablename
    group by ID
    having sum(case when StatusType = 'Cancelled' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
) dt
```

Or, do NOT EXISTS in a *correlated subquery*.

```
select count(distinct ID)
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t1.id = t2.id
                    and t2.StatusType = 'Cancelled')
```